# Php datetime function doesn't recognise dates before 1000

Tags: php

This code is used to take values inputted from a form but this does not take a year entered as 0100 as 0100 but as 1915, this is then used with the JS seen in one of my other questions any help here would be very good, I think the issue is something to do where the year is taken but I just can't get this to work correctly. Is this a limitation of php?

```
<?php
$year = "";
$month = "";
$day = "";

if (isset($_GET['year']) && !empty($_GET['year'])) {
    $year = $_GET['year'];
}

if (isset($_GET['month']) && !empty($_GET['month'])) {
    $month = $_GET['month'];

    $monthNumber = date('m', strtotime("$month 1 Y"));
}

if (isset($_GET['day']) && !empty($_GET['day'])) {
    $day = $_GET['day'];
}

if ($year != "" && $monthNumber != "" && $day != "") {





    $fullUrlDate = $year . "-" . $monthNumber . "-" . $day;

    $urlDate = new DateTime(date($fullUrlDate));
    $today =  new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

    $interval = $urlDate->diff($today);

    $gapYears = $interval->y;
    $gapMonths = $interval->m;
    $gapDays = $interval->d;
    $gapDaysTotal = $interval->days;
    $gapWeeksTotal = round($interval->days/7);
    $gapHours = $interval->h;
    $gapMinutes = $interval->i;
    $gapSeconds = $interval->s;

    if ($gapWeeksTotal == 1) {
        $gapWeeksSuffix = "";
    } else {
        $gapWeeksSuffix = "s";
    }   

    if ($gapDays == 1) {
        $gapDaysSuffix = "";
    } else {
        $gapDaysSuffix = "s";
    }   

    $ordinalSuffix = date("S", strtotime($fullUrlDate));

    if (strtotime($fullUrlDate) < strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) ) {
        $dateInThePast = true;
    } else {
        $dateInThePast = false;
    }

    // Months gap
    $monthsInterval = date_diff($urlDate, $today);
    $monthsGap = $monthsInterval->m + ($monthsInterval->y * 12);    

    $gapMonthsSuffix = ($monthsGap == 1 ? "" : "s");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` has no such limitation, but the `date` function you use to initialise it, does. You can use `DateTime::setDate` to set any year you want:

```
php > $a = new DateTime("2015-08-24");
php > echo $a->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
2015-08-24T00:00:00+0000

php > $a->setDate(90, 8, 24);
php > echo $a->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
0090-08-24T00:00:00+0000

php > $a->setDate(90090, 8, 24);
php > echo $a->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
90090-08-24T00:00:00+0000
```

Comment: I see what you mean, however I am not sure how I would implement this, the way in which the data is sent to the page is via the url so how would I get this to pick that up?

Comment: @L.Smith you can just call `$urlDate->setDate($year, $monthNumber, $day);`

Comment: @L.Smith I advise you to read up about object-oriented programming as well: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: @BartFriederichs, surely DateTime still runs from epoch? Or have I got the wrong idea about that?

Comment: @SamSwift no idea how `DateTime` is implemented. I reckon it is a little more extensive than just a 32-bit integer. There is a `getTimestamp` method that gets you the UNIX timestamp.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, I can confirm, using the code: `$d = new DateTime(); $d->setDate(1000, 1, 1); print $d->format("Y m d");`, what is printed to the client is: `1000 01 01`, turns out I was wrong!